# Can't properly center the footer div in a responsive manner

Tags: html, css

Here's a link to the GitHub containing the HTML file and CSS.  https://github.com/xenophenes/pgopen-splash2016

The issue is with the footer text, I can't figure out how to properly center the footer (it keeps being slightly off and gets more off when you resize the browser). Could someone assist in troubleshooting?

Thank you!

Comment: This would be easier if you used a fiddle...

Comment: Absolutely right - my bad, didn't consider that. Here's the fiddle. [https://jsfiddle.net/hc2yzshv/](https://jsfiddle.net/hc2yzshv/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your @media segments of the #footer in CSS.

Here is says if the max-width is X implement this sizing:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1680px) {

            #footer {
                bottom: 2em;
                left: 3.5em;
            }
        }
```

Simply remove it...

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1680px) {

            #footer {
                bottom: 2em;
            }
        }
```

And here too:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 736px) {

        #footer {
            text-align: center;
            bottom: 2em;
        }
```

Here is the fiddler link: https://jsfiddle.net/3yLpsLwq/

Comment: Oh gosh, thank you. I could've sworn I had tried removing that with no effect (maybe a cache effect?). Thanks!!!